# How to email the contents of multiple text inputs in a gallery to a specified user on button click in Power Apps?

Tags: office365, powerapps, powerapps-canvas

I am trying to set up a form for users to input their hours into multiple text input boxes and then send an email of this information as an excel file or pdf (if possible) to an user email address specified in another text input box.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have variety of connectors and trigger/actions in Flow to achieve in many ways, like Office 365 "Send an Email", Create file in OneDrive/SharePoint, etc.

What you can do is send the PowerApps content to Power Automate (Flow), from there you can generate pdf and attach to the email. This [community post](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/Send-pdf-created-after-submiting-form-in-attachment-by-microsoft/td-p/352778) will give you details steps to do it.

[image] [image]